# PhpStorm: error executing Behat tests No specifications found at path(s) but works from command line

Tags: symfony, vagrant, phpstorm, behat

I'm using PhpStorm and Vagrant to develop a Symfony project.

I configured PhpStorm to execute Behat tests with the Vagrant machine but when I try to run or debug them I got this error:

```
vagrant:///Users/jose/Documents/WWW/symfony_project/usr/bin/php /home/vagrant/.phpstorm_helpers/behat.php --format PhpStormBehatFormatter --config /var/www/symfony/behat.yml /var/www/symfony/features/api/brand/full_rest.feature:13
Testing started at 10:48 ...

0 scenario0 step0m0.05s (14.76Mb)


  [Behat\Testwork\Tester\Exception\WrongPathsException]                                                                                                                      
  No specifications found at path(s) `/var/www/symfony/features/api/brand/full_rest.feature:13`. This might be because of incorrect paths configuration in your `suites`.
```

Although if I execute it from the command line inside the Vagrant machine it works OK:

```
./vendor/bin/behat --config /var/www/symfony/behat.yml /var/www/symfony/features/api/brand/full_rest.feature:13
@brands @api
Feature: API to manage the brands
  As a frontend app
.......
```

I've configured the PHP Interpreter with my Vagrant VM and I also think the Behat configuration is set OK: I see the Behat version, I've set the behat config path... I don't understand why the execution from PhpStorm fails.

Any ideas? Thanks in advance

Comment: Maybe `symonfy` does not exist, seems there is a spelling issue.

Comment: @lauda sorry, that was a spelling issue but writting the question, actually paths are ok

Comment: The files like `behat.yml` and `full_rest.feature` are the same?

Comment: yes, absolutely, both are the same file shared between the vagrant host and the vm

Comment: What is the configuration of Behat in Preferences | Languages & Frameworks | PHP | Test Frameworks? Is it remote? Do you have a Vagrant configuration in Build, Execution, Deployment | Deployment? Are path mappings fine in the Mappings tab there?

Comment: Hi, seems like an issue with behat, I opened a issue on github and more people seem to have similar problems https://github.com/Behat/Behat/issues/1085. I downgraded to 3.0 and now it works with the same configuration

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This a bug in behat [3.4.0 breaks the ability to run individual tests](https://github.com/Behat/Behat/issues/1076)

Try to switch back to     "behat/behat": "3.3.1".